# How to fix JSON validation error on Echarts code

Tags: json, jsonlite

My json code is not being validated. I am new to Javascript. Hence I am finding difficulty to fix it. Json code shown below. I am using example from this https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple-

```
json <- paste0("
option = {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [820, 932, 901, 934, 1290, 1330, 1320],
        type: 'line'
    }]
};
")

json2 = gsub("\\s+", "", gsub('[\n\r]', "", json))
jsonlite::validate(json2)
```

**Error**

```
[1] "lexical error: invalid char in json text.\n                                       option={xAxis:{type:'category',\n                     (right here) ------^\n"
```